# How Tomcat start application without deployment descriptor (web.xml)?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a question about Tomcat and Servlet API.

If we have only a servlet class annotated with `@WebServlet("/user")` and don't have any `web.xml` descriptor than how Tomcat does look up for servlet class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think tomcat just scans classes and detects annotations WebServlet via reflection. So it interpret classes annotated with @WebServlet as servlets.